# Data Power Connectivity Errors

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, websphere, ibm-datapower

All

At times, when sending a request to our web service DataPower sends failure alerts wit the below error codes/messages

- 0x01130006: Failed to establish a backside connection
- 0x01130011: Failed to process response headers

I am not sure why this is happening, but I would guess the request is too big to process by DataPower, times out, and sends failure messages to the application.

I found a [forum](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14972592) suggesting to increase the thread count max on the Websphere servers, but it was never confirmed to be a working [or non working] solution.

I would like to know if someone has successfully resolved this issue with the above mentioned solution, or what other successful solutions are there.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Might be that someone trying to reach not excited uri . 
The error say faild established backside connection.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons for it namly,
1. You have conflicting routing information in datapower routing table about back end systems. In this case appliance will sometimes able to connect with backend and sometimes not.
2. The backend server is not able to respond in appropriate time [try to increase the 'back side timeout value].

To accuratly debug the issue you need to post the packet trace between datapower and backend systems [along with src and target IPs you are connecting to].

Are you also using load balancer on datapower to connect with backend?

- Ajitabh